# Delete <return> node and type attributes in Soap Zend Framework

Tags: php, xml, symfony, soap, zend-framework

I am developing a Web Service in Symfony 2 using Soap Zend Framework. I'm following this tutorial to guide me http://www.techtonet.com/symfony-create-a-soap-server-with-zend-soap.

The **Web Service works correctly**, I can send requests and get the answer I want, the **problem** comes with the answers that the framework sends.

Each time a response is returned, all of **my XML goes into a node** `<return xsi: type = "SOAP-ENC: Struct">`. Also, each tag that I generate, comes with its data type `<ip xsi: type = "xsd: string">`.

**Is there a way to return the XML that I generate as a response, without adding anything else?**

The function code that the XML returns:

```
/**
  * Return a test XML.
  * @return SimpleXml
  */
  public function ping()
  {
     $xml = '<ping>
        <ip>192.168.1.100</ip>
        <timestamp>2017-01-10T12:30:00</timestamp>
     </ping>';

     $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

     return $xml;
   }
```

And the answer I get from Soap Zend Framework:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://dev1.hodor/app_dev.php/api/f/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:pingResponse>
         <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
            <ip xsi:type="xsd:string">192.168.1.100</ip>
            <timestamp xsi:type="xsd:string">2017-01-10T12:30:00</timestamp>
         </return>
      </ns1:pingResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And the answer I would like to have is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://dev1.hodor/app_dev.php/api/f/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:pingResponse>
         <ip>192.168.1.100</ip>
         <timestamp>2017-01-10T12:30:00</timestamp>
      </ns1:pingResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The function that generates the response is the same as the one of the manual I am using to develop the Web Service

```
/**
  * execute SOAP request
  */
  public function handleSOAP($uri, $class)
  {
      // Soap server
      $soap = new Soap\Server(null,
          array('location' => $uri,
          'uri' => $uri,
      ));
      $soap->setClass($this->get($class));

      // Response
      $response = new Response();
      $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');

      ob_start();
      // Handle Soap
      $soap->handle();
      $response->setContent(ob_get_clean());
      return $response;
  }
```

Thank you.